# CakePHP writing files with different owner/group to server owner/group

Tags: php, cakephp, file-permissions, read-write

Am using CakePHP 2.2.2 and in order to write/delete files/symlinks to a folder have to set containing folder permissions to 0777 as writes seem to be using different owner/group names to those of CakePHP script files. This creates problems when using the same scripts to delete the files/symlinks that they created and also when trying change permissions/delete files via ftp client. Any pointers on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Who's running the script files? Apache? You? I mean whoever calls the script owns the process. What is the question here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your FTP user cannot delete the files created by the webserver. You have mainly two options:

- Let a PHP-script delete these files (so the files will be deleted by the owner who created them);
- Have a root- or admin-user delete these files.

The last one will be difficult on a shared hosting server, so the first one will probably be your way to go...